# How do I make Windows 10 Start Menu search find anything *containing* my search term (like Windows 7 did)?

Tags: windows, windows-10, start-menu, windows-search

On Windows 7: as I remember, the search results included anything that **contained** your search term.

On Windows 10: it seems, the search results only include items that **start with** your search term.

Here's an example, trying to open the `WinDirStat` program:

When I enter `dirst` I would expect it to find win**dirst**at because the .exe contains that search string. But there are no results.
[image: start menu search showing zero results]

On the other hand, if I enter `wind`, it immediately finds what I'm looking for, presumably because `WinDirStat` starts with `WinD`.
[image: start menu search showing what I was looking for]

The problem is, I <s>don't always</s> rarely actually remember the full name of what I'm looking for. For example, if I'm looking for `Win32DiskImager`, I'm not gonna remember it starts with `Win32`. Instead, I'd type `image`, in search of "that program I used a year ago to write a disk image to a disk".

Is there a simple fix or workaround for this? All I've found so far are 3rd party programs that change more than just this search behavior (ie [ClassicShell](http://www.classicshell.net/)). I don't want to change *everything*, just this search behavior.

Answer (score 3):

In Windows 10, v. 1909. there are apparently *different* search behaviors:

- Using Search from the Desktop, **wildcards (* and ?) are ignored**, as you've documented. Searches for `dirstat`, `*dirstat` and `*dirstat*` fail. [Others, such as respondent *harrymc*, have found wild cards *do* work, but not on the questioner's PC, nor on mine, with Windows 10 v. 1909, OS Build 18363.815.]

[image: Desktop Search ignoring wild card, *]

- Using Windows Explorer Search, there is no "automatic wild-card" at the beginning, so Search on `dirstat` fails:

[image: Explorer Search without wild-card]

- Using Windows Explorer Search, by adding the wild-card `*` at the beginning, Search on `dirstat` succeeds:

[image: Explorer Search using * wild-card]

- Finally, as you state, using [Classic Shell](http://classicshell.net/), or its successor, [Open-Shell-Menu](https://github.com/Open-Shell/Open-Shell-Menu), Desktop Search behaves as if it were using the  Cortana index and as if the search term were preceded and followed by wild-cards, instantly returning a result:

[image: Desktop Search using Classic Shell]

**You have at least two choices, then:**

1. Use Windows Explorer to search, and precede the term with an asterisk.
2. Use an add-on, such as Classic Shell, which provides the old functionality (though I do understand you do not want to try that).

Answer (score 2):

As you have already found out, Search from the taskbar in Windows 10 is not very efficient, and wildcards don't work.

if you are only interested in finding a file quickly (but not their contents) irrespective of whether you type a portion of the file name, then you can install this small utility: [Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/downloads/).

> What is "Everything"?
>
> "Everything" is search engine that locates files and folders by filename instantly for Windows.
>
> Unlike Windows search "Everything" initially displays every file and folder on your computer (hence the name "Everything").
>
> You type in a search filter to limit what files and folders are displayed.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple fix or workaround for this: Use wildcards.
Instead of searching for "string", search for "*string" (at least).

This problem dates to Windows Vista, when Microsoft changed its search from
character-based to word-based, as documented in the blog
[Character based versus word based search, or Searching with wildcards on Windows Vista](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jonasbar/character-based-versus-word-based-search-or-searching-with-wildcards-on-windows-vista):

> On Windows XP search is character based. That is, if you search for a
> string 'test', it will find files named 'my test data.doc',
> 'additional testing.xls' as well as 'latest junk.txt' or (if you tell
> it to search also contents of files) files containing words such as
> 'test', 'tester' and 'fattest'.
>
> On Windows Vista, and on Windows XP with WDS installed, search is
> normally word based. Searching for the string 'test' will only find
> documents with the word 'test' in them, or words beginning with
> 'test'. So it will find the files named 'my test data.doc' and
> 'additional testing.xls' but it will not find 'latest junk.txt'.
> Moreover, it will find documents containing 'test' or 'tester' but it
> will not find documents containing 'fattest'.
>
> The main reason for the change is that by making search word based one
> can use an index to make searches much faster.

Comment: As a remark, ClassicShell is discontinued, use instead
[Open-Shell](https://github.com/Open-Shell/Open-Shell-Menu).

Comment: in my test of Windows 10, v. 1909, Desktop Search, *wild cards (* or ?) no longer work*. They *do* work using Search in Windows Explorer.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: Same version, and it works for me in the Start menu.

Comment: using Windows 10 v. 1909, OS Build 18363.815. So it seems that *some* versions perform search correctly, others don't. But MS doesn't need QC, because it adds no value to the product. *sigh*

Comment: @harrymc Version 2004 here. For me wildcards don't work either. Wildcards are simply ignored, i.e. searching for `timerecording` OR `*timerecording*` will find `workplace_timerecording.xs` and `workplace timerecording.xls` but *not* `workplacetimerecording.xls` or `workplace-timerecording.xls`. Maybe the convention you used just happens to make the wildcards being ignored irrelevant? The current rule seems to be "match words beginning with the query" (searching form `timerec` would give me the same results), with "words" being defined by specific separator constructs.

Comment: @kdb: Windows version 20H2 here, and it's still working for me.

Comment: @harrymc Looks like 20H2 is just a different name for 2004. (yay for confusion...). Can you post a screenshot of query and result? We may be just misunderstanding each other... Here my outcomes: https://imgur.com/a/PaSiqx5

Comment: @kdb: I checked this on Explorer and it works. I don't use the Microsoft Start menu that changes with each release, but a replacement, so cannot duplicate your findings.

Comment: @harrymc In Explorer it does work, yes. But this question was always about the start menu.

Comment: @kdb That is incorrect: they are not the same. Version 2004 is from April-2020 (hence 2020-04), whereas "20H2" is from October 2020 (hence 2020-H2).